# I have problems with ł, ó, ą type characters in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a piece of code in my iOS app that should go through a word and check if a character is in it. When it finds at least one, it should change a string full of "_" of the same length as the word to one with the character in the right place:

```
wordToGuess = six
letterGuessed = i
wordAsUnderscores = _i_
```

The code works. But I start to have problems when I type in characters like: "ć", "ł", "ą", etc. From using `character.utf8.count` I saw that Swift thinks those are not 1 but 2 characters. So I get something like this:

```
wordToGuess = cześć
letterGuessed = ś
wordAsUnderscores = _ _ ś (place filled with empty char) _
```

It takes up 2 places.

I was at it for 6 hours and didn't figure out how to fix it, so I'm asking you guys for help.

Code that is supposed to do that:

```
let characterGuessed = Character(letterGuessed)

for index in wordToGuess.indices {
    if (wordToGuess[index] == characterGuessed) {
        let endIndex = wordToGuess.index(after: index)
        let charRange = index..<endIndex

        wordAsUnderscores = wordAsUnderscores.replacingCharacters(in: charRange, with: letterGuessed)
        wordToGuessLabel.text = wordAsUnderscores
    }
}
```

I would like the code to treat "ć", "ł", "ą" characters the same as "i", "a" and so on. I don't want them to be treated as 2.

Comment: You need to show how `letterGuessed` is declared and initialized. Same for `wordAsUnderscores`.

Comment: var wordAsUnderscores : String = "" and guard let letterGuessed = inputTextFieldProperties.text else { return }

Comment: `characters.utf8.count` counts UTF-8 code units. Non-ASCII characters are represented with multiple code units, so it's not the right way to count the number of characters in a string. You should be able to use `characters.count`.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *reason* is that you cannot use indices from one string (`wordToGuess`) for subscripting another string (`wordAsUnderscores`). Generally, indices of one collection must not be used with a different collection. (There are exception like `Array` though).

Here is a working variant:

```
let wordToGuess = "cześć"
let letterGuessed: Character = "ś"

var wordAsUnderscores = "c____"

wordAsUnderscores = String(zip(wordToGuess, wordAsUnderscores)
    .map { $0 == letterGuessed ? letterGuessed : $1 })

print(wordAsUnderscores) // c__ś_
```

The strings are traversed in parallel, and for each correctly guessed character in `wordToGuess` the corresponding character in `wordAsUnderscores` is replaced by that character.